# Uploadify : How to get src file full path

Tags: asp.net, file, file-upload, uploadify

I'm using uploadify feature to upload various files to the server and even it working great for me.
The one thing I'v stuck is - while getting source file full path.

As,I know in ASP.net File Upload control serves the source file like

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

string srcFilePath= FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

Here my request, similarly how can we get the source file path via Uploadify ...

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: are you asking for Client File path or Server file path??

Comment: @Shashank Client File path .... e.g: C:\Doc\xyz.doc

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer is that you cant. 
i havent used uploadify 
but due to security restrictions of the browser the full path of the file isn't sent to the server. None of the nwerner browsers send the full file name. only some of the older browsers(IE) support this.

It is independent of the plugin/control you are using

Comment: But the ASP.Net Upload control allows us to get the full source file path  -- string srcFilePath=FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName; then in the same way i wish to get posted file path :)

Comment: have you checked that.. getting full path

Comment: Yeah.. before posting a question,I have done a sample demo app with File Upload control.... and I was able to get srFilePath..:)

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: probably thats why.. try gaain using a new version of ie or chrome.. and you will know what im saying

Comment: Sir.. there is not yet all issue with browser/brower version/browser type.I'm seeking the solution for Uploadify version to get the SRCFILEPATH  Any help is appreciated.:)